# Use graph as input object by allowing the user to move chart-lines up and down or from left to right (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, graph, charts

I am wondering if there is a way to use a graph in Javascript/jquery not only as an output object to visualize data but also to use it for input as the user can move the charts with the cursor?

Thanks,
Lukas

Comment: did you figure out a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately not